# Neo4j: which query-approach for selecting single node based on node property and position?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, gremlin

I am having trouble evaluating when to use which Neo4j query-mechanism (Gremlin, Cypher, traversals, build-in algorithms). For instance, I would like to select the single node in the entire graph

- with the highest number of edges;
- within a certain path-lenght from one of 4 starting nodes;
- having a certain value for a property.

I am using the Python [neo4jrestclient](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client), and can execute basic Gremlin/Cypher scripts & traversals for some of the requirements individually (e.g. calculating In/OutDegree with Gremlin), but am missing the bigger picture on how to combine them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: But the problem is with the [neo4jrestclient](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client/) or the query itself?

Comment: The client is working OK, I am more wondering what query-mechanism to use where.

Comment: It mostly depends on you preferences, traversals are fastest, cypher is more convenient. But you should watch out as some of what you want to do are graph-global queries which are not the optimal use-case for Neo4j.

Comment: Are you indexing the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cypher it would look like this:

```
start n=node:index(indicator="startnode-value")
match n-[:REL*..10]->target
where target.prop = "value"
return target
```